# How to create a function that receives a function, calls it and returns it on C++?

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to create a function that receives a function, calls it and returns it back. I've tried several things already, including a lot of template combinations, an none seems to work. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Post the code that you've written to try and solve this.

Comment: Did you tried function pointer? Maybe you should show your code here to make clear.

Comment: I have tried so many things that I'm not sure what I should post...

Comment: Keywords "functor" and "lambda", which you could arrive at by searching for "c++ function as function argument/parameter".

Comment: @kfsone good are your intentions but please avoid [pointing people to Google on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links). It is considered harmful for some reasons.

Comment: Gotta have a little light fun now and again or this place gets too much like work :)

Comment: Lets hope nobody noticed the 5s where I changed the links to zombo.com before removing them ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
template <typename Functor>
Functor your_function(Functor toCall)
{
    toCall();
    return toCall;
}
```

---

If you want to return what the functor returns, then you'd use something like:

```
// Requires C++11
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Functor>
typename std::result_of<Functor()>::type your_function(Functor toCall)
{
    return toCall();
}
```

Also note that this will get easier in C++14 with `decltype(auto)`:

```
//Requires C++14    
template <typename Functor>
decltype(auto) your_function(Functor toCall)
{
    return toCall();
}
```

Comment: +1 and thanks, I didn't know the word 'functor' just searched after reading this answer :)

Comment: Enlightening, thanks! For further learning, could you be kind enough, and point how do I return **what the function returns** (not it itself)?

Comment: OK that sounds very complicated but is exactly what I wanted to know, thanks.

Comment: @Jerry: Somehow I don't think beginners are making that kind of a distinction :)

Comment: @Viclib: Note that this gets easier in C++14 (See code example above)

Comment: @BillyONeal ok that is much better if yet a little magical. I didn't even know C++14 existed, though. I guess it is barely supported today?

Comment: Also, may I ask again, is the function actually converted to a Functor when I send it? I thought a functor was a struct which overloaded the () operator. That sounds a little magical to me.

Comment: @Viclib: C++14 is not yet an ISO standard -- it is still going through the voting process.

Comment: The function is not converted to a functor. "Functor" is just a word that means "a function object", be that a function pointer or an object overloading `operator()`. Really though, the word doesn't matter -- you could say `template <typename Fish>
Fish your_function(Fish toCall)` if you wanted. When you call `your_function`, the function template is instantiated, and the typename gets "fancy pants find and replace"'d with whatever the actual type of the parameter is.

Answer (score 5):

One function can't receive another function as a parameter -- C didn't allow it, and C++ doesn't either.

You can, however, pass a *pointer to a function* as a parameter, then invoke the function via that pointer.

```
#include <iostream>

int f() { std::cout << "called f\n"; return 2; }

typedef int (*ptr)();

int g(ptr p) { return p(); }

int main(){
    std::cout << g(f);
}
```

Result:

```
called f
2
```

If you're willing to use a function *template* instead of a function, you can pass the name of a function as a template parameter and invoke that. In *most* cases, it's preferable to use a functor (an instance of a class that overloads `operator()` so it can be invoked like a function) instead of a function though.

Answer (score 2):

algorithm:

1. make the function receive a parameter which is a function pointer.
2. invoke the function using the function pointer.
3. return the function pointer.
   Functions are not first-class objects in C and C++. So you will need to use pointers to functions.

Comment: You should accept callable objects (e.g. `std::less`) in addition to function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the syntax for a function that is passed a function pointer as one of its parameters:

```
int Func (int (*funcToCall) (int, int)) /* This is how to receive the function as a parameter */
{
    int val = funcToCall (1, 2); /* This is how to call the function once it's received as a parameter */
    return (val);
}
int FuncToBePassed (int x, int y) /* This is a sample function that fits the format we need to pass into Func */
{
    return (x+y);
}
printf ("%d\n", Func (FuncToBePassed)); /* This is how to pass the function reference to the first function */
```

So, in this example, we have a function (FuncToBePassed) with two int parameters and then a function (Func) that expects to be passed a function like FuncToBePassed.  Finally, the last line of code is doing just that, calling Func and passing it a reference to FuncToBePassed.

By the way, if you're not totally committed to using C++, I'd strongly recommend using C# instead, as details like passing functions around are MUCH better designed.  So, if you're going to spend time mastering a language, go for the one that will be more practical.  Unless you're maintaining some code that's already in C++, which is understandable...  Hope I answered your question!